# MariaDB is returning undefined once I export the results

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mariadb

### I am working on a small Express js app, using MariaDB

Whenever I started looking around on how to use mariaDB in my app, I always found examples where **the connection** and **queries** are directly written into the routes.

I thought this was not very readable and am trying to seperate the two.

- route calls for the query (e.g. `User.getAll()`)
- The `User.getAll()` which is being imported from `User.mjs` returns the response from the DB.

### My problem:

So far, this is how I thought it would need to be:

**User.mjs**

```js
const User = {
    all: async () => {
        let conn;
        try {
            conn = await pool.getConnection()
            const rows = await conn.query(`SELECT * FROM users`);

            console.log(rows) // Shows list in terminal as expected
            return rows // does not return to where it's being called..

        } catch (err) {
            throw err;
        } finally {
            if (conn) return conn.end();
        }
    }
}

export default User;
```

Which is then being used in my User router as follows:

**userRouter.mjs**

```js
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const data = await User.all();
    console.log(data); // Shows "undefined" in terminal
    // Eventually also res.json(data);
})
```

### The query works...

When I call my function in my router, it does execute the query and my **console.log(rows)** shows exactly what I want.

But my **console.log(data)** from my router returns **undefined**.

Am I missing something? Or is this not a good way of doing it? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return inside the `finally` block is overwriting the return from inside the `try` block. And since `conn.end()` returns a `Promise` that resolves without an argument, you get `undefined` when awaiting it.

A simpler example that shows the same issue:

```js
function f() {
  try {
    return 1;
  } finally {
    return;
  }
}
console.log(f());
```

Comment: Seems like that was the issue indeed, TY! is it considered ok to remove the return in the if statement and just say `if (conn) conn.end();`, then I can return the result (containing the rows) `return result; // contains the values of rows`?

Comment: @Basile You can keep your original function and just remove the return before `conn.end()`. Add `await` in front of it if you want conn.end to complete before leaving the function.